# Carousel made by Viewpager using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` causes `NullPointerException`

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

As title,
I've had a Carousel like the following image shows:

[Carousel_Normal_status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gmbb.jpg)

this is the normal status, and when I use the `FragmentPagerAdapter` for it,
everything's just worked fine, but since I've infinite pages to show in it, 
I had to use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to avoid the fast-swiped buggy,
but after I made the change:

[After using FragmentStatePagerAdapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfKLB.jpg)

Many defined behavior has gone, and `NullPointerException` has been detected:

```
06-07 18:59:39.003 9266-9266/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
06-07 18:59:39.003 9266-9266/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
06-07 18:59:39.149 9266-9266/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.kiahstarck.exercise-2/lib/x86
06-07 18:59:39.162 9266-9266/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
06-07 18:59:39.362 9266-9266/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
06-07 18:59:39.754 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{c30bbd8 #0 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:39.785 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{3891216 #1 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:39.813 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{9e1bd84 #2 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:39.828 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{2fc39a2 #3 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:39.852 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{47f2df0 #4 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:39.877 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{f884dee #5 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:39.932 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{e41391c #6 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:40.083 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{4af5afa #7 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:40.095 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{2b6cb08 #8 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:40.100 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{9e112a1 #9 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:40.102 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{2082cc6 #10 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:40.105 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{2439487 #11 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:40.107 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{5718fb4 #12 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:40.111 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{45b37dd #13 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:40.117 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{7ca4f52 #14 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:40.118 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{baf223 #15 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:40.120 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{f71f320 #16 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:40.122 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{65874d9 #17 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:40.124 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{1a0e9e #18 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:40.125 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{7c08d7f #19 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:40.126 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{753214c #20 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:40.127 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{f528595 #21 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:40.129 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{11476aa #22 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:40.131 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{35a829b #23 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:40.132 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{370638 #24 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:40.133 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{2a2e611 #25 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:40.135 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{39b5376 #26 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:40.136 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{fd4ad77 #27 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:40.138 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{b724de4 #28 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:40.140 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{5bed24d #29 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:40.142 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{ae13102 #30 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:40.144 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{85caa13 #31 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:40.144 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{8f86450 #32 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:40.145 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{6334649 #33 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:40.146 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{8b55b4e #34 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:40.147 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{35dd46f #35 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:40.148 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{287757c #36 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:40.149 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{360fe05 #37 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:40.151 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{a8fde5a #38 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:40.152 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for ItemFragment{89d488b #39 id=0x7f0c005f} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-07 18:59:40.155 9266-9268/com.kiahstarck.exercise I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=30KB, data=28KB
06-07 18:59:40.156 9266-9268/com.kiahstarck.exercise I/art: After code cache collection, code=30KB, data=28KB
06-07 18:59:40.156 9266-9268/com.kiahstarck.exercise I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
06-07 18:59:40.198 9266-9290/com.kiahstarck.exercise I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-07 18:59:40.198 9266-9290/com.kiahstarck.exercise D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
06-07 18:59:40.198 9266-9290/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
06-07 18:59:40.198 9266-9290/com.kiahstarck.exercise D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
06-07 18:59:40.238 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise D/onpage: offset   0
06-07 18:59:40.239 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'com.kiahstarck.exercise.CarouselRelativeLayout com.kiahstarck.exercise.ItemFragment.root' on a null object reference
06-07 18:59:40.239 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at com.kiahstarck.exercise.CarouselPagerAdapter.onPageScrolled(CarouselPagerAdapter.java:81)
06-07 18:59:40.240 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dispatchOnPageScrolled(ViewPager.java:1850)
06-07 18:59:40.240 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onPageScrolled(ViewPager.java:1824)
06-07 18:59:40.240 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.pageScrolled(ViewPager.java:1762)
06-07 18:59:40.240 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.scrollToItem(ViewPager.java:633)
06-07 18:59:40.240 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1706)
06-07 18:59:40.240 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
06-07 18:59:40.240 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
06-07 18:59:40.240 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
06-07 18:59:40.240 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
06-07 18:59:40.240 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
06-07 18:59:40.240 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
06-07 18:59:40.240 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
06-07 18:59:40.240 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
06-07 18:59:40.240 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
06-07 18:59:40.240 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
06-07 18:59:40.240 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
06-07 18:59:40.240 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
06-07 18:59:40.240 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
06-07 18:59:40.240 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
06-07 18:59:40.240 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
06-07 18:59:40.241 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
06-07 18:59:40.241 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
06-07 18:59:40.241 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
06-07 18:59:40.241 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
06-07 18:59:40.241 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
06-07 18:59:40.241 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
06-07 18:59:40.241 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
06-07 18:59:40.241 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
06-07 18:59:40.241 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
06-07 18:59:40.241 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
06-07 18:59:40.241 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:726)
06-07 18:59:40.241 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
06-07 18:59:40.241 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
06-07 18:59:40.241 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2346)
06-07 18:59:40.241 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2068)
06-07 18:59:40.241 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
06-07 18:59:40.241 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6337)
06-07 18:59:40.241 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
06-07 18:59:40.241 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
06-07 18:59:40.241 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
06-07 18:59:40.242 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
06-07 18:59:40.242 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
06-07 18:59:40.242 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-07 18:59:40.242 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
06-07 18:59:40.242 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
06-07 18:59:40.242 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-07 18:59:40.242 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
06-07 18:59:40.242 9266-9266/com.kiahstarck.exercise W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Suddenly two classes that're obviously existed can't be read,
so it might be the API buggy, I checked solution and although there're many people facing the same issue but the detail is quite different, the solutions of it didn't work for me as well.

Totally have no idea, will be very grateful if anyone knows the solution.
Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Fix this by discovering that `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` does not define Ids & tags for fragments.

Need to use instantiate method of adapter to request the fragment's reference.